# Selenium standalone server is stuck in endless loop on Mac

Tags: java, r, selenium-webdriver

I was tying to start my selenium standalone server in R with this code:

```
system("java -jar /Users/macbook/Documents/R/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -port 4200")
```

If I do this, my R code gets stuck in an endless loop at that line of code, so that the following code does not get executed. Same if I try it through the Mac terminal (I can't type in the next command because the previous one is running endless). The server is stuck after saying:

```
Selenium Server is up and running
```

I do not have the problem with the 4.8.0 version of Selenium standalone server (yes, I used different ports), but I need the 2.53.1 version running too.

I also tried the "&" at the end of the code so that the code runs in the background. In this case the code does not get stuck, but I can't execute the next lines of code anyway because R says that the port is already in use.

```
system("java -jar /Users/macbook/Documents/R/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -port 4200 &")
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `system` function has a parameter `wait = TRUE`, if you set this to FALSE then it should run the command asynchronously.

```r
system("java -jar /Users/macbook/Documents/R/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -port 4200", wait = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey, thank for your answer! The code moved on, but now I have the following problem:

Next line of code:
rsDriver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 4200L)

Error:
Error in wdman::selenium(port = port, verbose = verbose, version = version,  : 
  Selenium server signals port = 4206 is already in use.

It seems like the server running in the background blocks the port, so that my driver in R can't work with the port.

Comment: You are a running the Selenium driver twice. Once with the call to system() and once with the call to rsDriver(). If you are simply creating a web driver to scrape data from the web or navigate to websites you can follow the example in the help file of ?RSelenium::rsDriver. Or use the webdriver package from RStudio instead and follow the instructions on this GitHub page: https://github.com/rstudio/webdriver